# How to send JSON data from client to Django websocket server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to create Django server to receive JSON data fast from external client (sensor), so I decided to go from classic HTTP to consumers. I can add data from admin page and from REST framework page, but I can't send anything via test client (browser extention). Here is my consume.py (based on this repo [live-data-drf-channels](https://github.com/jha-shubham01/live-data-drf-channels/tree/main)).

```
# consumers.py
from djangochannelsrestframework.generics import GenericAsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.mixins import ListModelMixin

from djangochannelsrestframework.observer import model_observer

from . import models, serializers


class PostConsumer(ListModelMixin, GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):
    queryset = models.SensorsValue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SensorsValueSerializer()
    # permissions = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    authentication_classes = []  # disables authentication
    permission_classes = []

    async def connect(self, **kwargs):
        await super().connect()
        await self.model_change.subscribe()
        print("Connected")

    @model_observer(models.SensorsValue)
    async def model_change(self, message, **kwargs):
        print("JSON")
        await self.send_json(message)

    @model_change.serializer
    def model_serialize(self, instance, action, request_id=None, **kwargs):
        print(dict(data=serializers.SensorsValueSerializer(instance=instance).data, action=action.value))
        return dict(data=serializers.SensorsValueSerializer(instance=instance).data, action=action.value)

    async def disconnect(self, message):
        print("Disconnected")
        await super().disconnect(message)
```

My test client is connecting and disconnecting correctly, but every time I try to add new data like:
{"data": {"timer": 3, "accX": 10.0, "accY": 10.0, "accZ": 10.0, "gyrX": 10.0, "gyrY": 10.0, "gyrZ": 10.0}, "action": "create"}
I get this error:

```
Exception inside application: 'request_id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 101, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 116, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 50, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 194, in websocket_receive
    await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 257, in receive
    await self.receive_json(await self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Natalia\Desktop\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\djangochannelsrestframework\consumers.py", line 195, in receive_json
    request_id = content.pop("request_id")
KeyError: 'request_id'
```

I tried adding random request_id into JSON object, but I get error in client console:
`{"errors": ["Method \"create\" not allowed."], "data": null, "action": "create", "response_status": 405, "request_id": "33"}`

How do I add request_id to my JSON or how do I change my consumer to not check request_id?

I tried adding "request_id" to JSON object, but however I do it, I receive error from client or from server.

**EDIT**
I found an answer, although it is probably not the "correct" one (it works, but raises syntax warning). I have added this method in my PostConsumer:

```
   async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    start = time()
    incoming = json.loads(text_data)
    try:
        incoming
    except NameError:
        print("Faulty data")
    else:
        data = incoming
        print(data)
        if type(data) == list:
            model_list = []
            model_list = [models.SensorsValue(**x) for x in data]
            # await sync_to_async(models.SensorsValue.objects.bulk_create(model_list))()
            await models.SensorsValue.objects.abulk_create(model_list, batch_size=10)
            print("Elapsed time {}.".format(time() - start))
        else:
            m = models.SensorsValue(**data)
            await sync_to_async(m.save)()

        print("Message received")
```

I would appreciate if someone would give the most correct way to do it.